# Output each type from type list on a seperate line

Tags: haskell

```
type FirstName = String
type Surname = String
type Age = Int
type Id = Int
type Student = (FirstName, Surname, Age, Id)
testData :: [Student]
testData = [("Garry", "Queen", 10, 1),
    ("Jerry", "Bob", 11, 2),
    ("Amy", "Big", 9, 3)]
```

I am trying to output each students information on a new line using the testData.
How would I go about doing this?

I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
studentToString :: Student FirstName Surname Age Id -> String
studentToString (Student FirstName Surname Age Id) = FirstName ++ Surname ++ Age ++ Id

studentsToString :: [Student] -> String
studentsToString (x:xs) = putStrLn(studentToString x) ++ studentsToString xs
```

It gave me an error

```
error: Not in scope: data constructor ‘Student’
```

for this line

```
studentToString :: Student FirstName Surname Age Id -> String
```

Comment: You can also use the function `lines` so you only need one string and one `putStrLn`

Answer (score 1):

In your definition, `Student` is a type alias, not a data constructor, therefore you cannot use it in the way you intended. It would be as if you wrote:

```
studentToString :: Student FirstName Surname Age Id -> String
studentToString :: (FirstName, Surname, Age, Id) FirstName Surname Age Id -> String
```

Not much sense there. One way to fix this is to convert your `Student` definition to a data constructor:

```
data Student = Student FirstName Surname Age Id

studentToString :: Student -> String
...
```

One neat trick of data constructors is that it will let you use pattern matching on the wrapped values, just as if it were a tuple:

```
getAge :: Student -> Age
getAge (Student _ _ age _) = age

getId :: Student -> Id
getId (Student _ _ _ id) = id

...
```

Comment: How would I format the test data with this solution? I've tried removing commas, changing brackets but nothing seems to work.

Comment: @Dilly `testData = [ Student "Garry" "Queen" 10 1, ... ]`

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid to say that there are very many things wrong with your code. I'll try to go through them one at a time and adapt this to a working solution.

1) This line:

```
type Student = (FirstName, Surname, Age, Id)
```

declares what is known as a "type synonym". It just makes `Student` mean exactly the same thing to the compiler as the 4-tuple `(FirstName, Surname, Age, Id)`.  You could instead have done this:

```
data Student = Student FirstName Surname Age Id
```

which would have made `Student` into a completely new type, which you can construct values of by using a function - also called `Student`, the "data constructor" on the right of the `=` sign (you could assign any name to this, but it's conventional to use the same name as that of the type itself) - applied to values of types `FirstName`, `Surname`, `Age` and `Id`.

While I think most experienced Haskell programmers (which I'm not, just a developer who is interested in the language and tries to dabble when I get the chance) would prefer the `data` declaration because it is more "type safe" (there is no risk of confusing a `Student` with some 4-tuple of the same types which is intended to be something else), I think the type synonym which you have is fine for casual use, and I'll continue with this below.

Anyway, your first problem is with the type signature of the `studentToString` function. As I said, `Student` is a type in its own right, in this case a synonym for a particular type of 4-tuple. Although it has fields of the 4 types you've listed in the signature, it is a type in its own right, and doesn't need - and therefore cannot have - other types after it in order to make a valid type. This is nonsensical here. The input type of your function is a `Student` - that is, a 4-tuple. So the type signature should be simply:

```
studentToString :: Student -> String
```

(As an aside, that fits rather neatly with the accurate name that you've given the function.)

2) You've got similarly confused with the function definition itself:

```
studentToString (Student FirstName Surname Age Id) = ...
```

This won't compile, for the reason GHC is giving you in the error message. It only knows `Student` as the name of a type, and in order for this definition to make sense it would have to also be the name of a function - specifically a constructor function. As I mentioned above, you could have made this happen by using a `data` declaration for `Student`, rather than a type synonym. But this isn't what you've done. Your `Student` type, as I've said, is simply a 4-tuple, so you have to define the function in such a way that it accepts a 4-tuple. In addition, uppercase identifiers like `FirstName` refer to types and type constructors, while you want lowercase identifiers like `firstName` which refer to functions and variables. So you should do this instead:

```
studentToString (firstName, surname, age, id) = ...
```

3) You also have a type mismatch on the right hand side of the function definition. The `++` operator is used to put lists (of the same type) together into a bigger list. It's fine and normal to do this with strings, because Haskell strings are simply lists of characters. (There are performance reasons not to do this if it's for a performance-critical application, or if your strings will be huge - but don't worry about this for simple learning exercises like this.)

But the problem is that `age` and `id` will have type `Int`, not `String`. You can't use `++` with them at all - an `Int` is not a list, and certainly not a list of `Char`. Unlikely many languages, Haskell will not happily convert numbers to strings for you when used in a "string context". It has a static and very strict type system which simply does not allow you to use values of the wrong type at any point. (In other respects the type system can be very flexible, due to typeclasses and polymorphic functions, as you'll discover as you learn more about the language. But converting a numerical type to a string representation is not something it will do for you.)

So you have to do the conversion explicitly - and Haskell has a simple function for this, called `show`. Without being too technical, it basically converts anything into a string that can reasonably be converted. So, putting this together with all my previous comments, a working version of `studentToString` would be:

```
studentToString :: Student -> String
studentToString (firstName, surname, age, id) = firstName ++ surname ++ show age ++ show id
```

4) A minor point - the above will compile fine, but for practical purposes you probably want to space out the different parts of the output string:

```
studentToString :: Student -> String
studentToString (firstName, surname, age, id) = firstName ++ " " ++ surname ++ " " ++ show age ++ " " ++ show id
```

5) Moving on now to your second function, `studentsToString`, there is a fundamental type mismatch in your attempted implementation:

```
studentsToString :: [Student] -> String
studentsToString (x:xs) = putStrLn(studentToString x) ++ studentsToString xs
```

Your type signature proclaims that the output will be a `String` (as does the name!). Yet `putStrLn` does *not* output a `String`! It outputs a value of type `IO ()` - without going too deeply into Haskell's type system and how it handles I/O in a pure way, we can say that this is not the same thing, precisely because it has a "side effect" (printing some output to the terminal). Nothing in Haskell has any side effects - all values are "pure" - except for those whose type begins with `IO`. Basically a value of type `IO ()` is an "action" that, when executed, does something in the "outside world" (in this case, prints something), and returns no useful value of its own. (And note that merely making such an "action" in your code does not execute its effects - that does happen though when you run your final program, or output such a value in GHCi.)

So your function is frankly a bit confused. You can either convert the list of students to a string (a pure operation) and then try to output the result. Or you could simply make the function output the result, using a return value of `IO ()`.

Here, quicky, is how I might do both of these. First, the pure function could be (note how similar it is to your faulty version):

```
studentsToString :: [Student] -> String
studentsToString [] = ""
studentsToString (x:xs) = studentToString x ++ ", " ++ studentsToString xs
```

All I have really changed is removing the `putStrLn` so that you get a "pure" `String` result. I've also added a "base case" for the empty list - without this your function will crash because each recursive step acts on a shorter list, and eventually it'll reach the empty list and fail because the `(x:xs)` pattern doesn't match an empty list.

Finally, and least importantly, I've added some "padding" between each output value, so they don't all run on together. I've chosen a comma and space, but this is arbitrary. You may prefer a newline - or indeed anything else.

Having done that, you can just run `putStrLn (studentsToString testData)` in GHCi, to output the result. (Although the `putStrLn` isn't necessary, GHCi always prints any expression you give it.)

Finally, here is a very simple - and slightly more advanced - way in which you could output the test data, one student on each line:

```
mapM_ (putStrLn . studentToString) testData
```

To understand this fully you have to know a bit about Monads - which, trust me, are not as scary as they sound - but it basically makes an "action" (like a small program) that "loops" over the `testData` list, applies `studentToString` to each element, and prints each on a new line.